How to pass an untyped dictionary assigned to a variable to a method that expects a TypedDict without mypy complaining?
I would like to pass a dictionary to a method foo that expects a TypedDict without explicitly mentioning the type. When I pass the dictionary directly to the method, everything is good. However, when I assign the dictionary to a variable configs first, mypy complains about incompatible types. Interestingly, PyCharm does not complain about foo(configs) as long as configs contains the correct keys and values. I could add type information to configs at [1] below but wonder if I could improve the typing to make the usage of foo and Params less verbose.
from typing import TypedDict


class Params(TypedDict):
    a: str
    b: str


def foo(config: Params):
    pass


foo({"a": "a", "b": "b"})  # Okay

configs = {"a": "a", "b": "b"}  # [1]
foo(configs)  # error: Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "dict[str, str]"; expected "Params"  [arg-type]


That's what you explicitly asked for. With def foo(config: Params): you're saying "this can't just accept any old dict, it must have the a and b keys with str values". But configs is just dict[str, str].

@jonrsharpe: configs is an old dict but with the required keys and PyCharm does some analysis that figures that out. I could theoretically add and remove keys after configs has been assigned and before passing it to foo. That makes type inference of dict[str, str] reasonable. But I don't add or delete keys. And I was hoping I can tell mypy that somehow. But that might be a bit much to ask of the type system.

Wrap the dict literal in a call to Params or add an explicit type annotation to the configs variable:
from typing import TypedDict


class Params(TypedDict):
    a: str
    b: str


def foo(config: Params):
    pass


foo({"a": "a", "b": "b"})

configs = Params({"a": "a", "b": "b"})  # Either...
configs: Params = {"a": "a", "b": "b"}  # ...or
foo(configs)

Notably, neither of the two approaches does runtime validation.

The correct way seems to be specific, go ahead and type configs implicitly or explicitly. In combination with @SHresTho12 's answer, the two to three most common ways to do so when working with TypedDict have been proposed. Thank you!

The issue you're encountering is due to the fact that while the dictionary you are passing to foo matches the Params type in structure, Python's type system doesn't automatically infer that configs has the same structure as Params. cast Function can be used for this. Here cast tells the type checker to treat configs as if it were of type Params. This resolves the type mismatch issue with mypy.
from typing import TypedDict, cast

class Params(TypedDict):
    a: str
    b: str

def foo(config: Params):
    pass

foo({"a": "a", "b": "b"})  # Okay

configs = {"a": "a", "b": "b"}
foo(cast(Params, configs))  # Okay with type assertion

Alternatively this works too . This approach makes it explicit that configs should be treated as a Params type, which helps both mypy and editors like PyCharm understand the type better.
configs: Params = {"a": "a", "b": "b"}
foo(configs)  # Okay


I would advise against using cast, as it will effectively disable any type-checking.
